# Excel VBA to create Pivot, no table appearing

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

The VBA code I have below is trying to create a Pivot Table based on data in "Sheet2", adding a new sheet "Pivot Table" and creating a Pivot Table on this sheet.

However the code is executing without error, just no table appears on the new sheet "Pivot Table" and I cannot see why.

Also the data on Sheet2 for the PT currently begins in column B, not sure if this is having an effect.

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")



'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")



'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")



'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MilestonePivotTable").PivotFields("Resource Name")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MilestonePivotTable").PivotFields("Deliverable")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MilestonePivotTable").PivotFields("Milestone Date")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With
```

[image]

Comment: If your data starts in column B, shouldn't `PRange` be set as `Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "B").Resize(LastRow, LastCol - 1)`?

Comment: First try fully qualifying your Rows and Columns part where you find the last row by prefixing them with `DSheet.` It will be using `ActiveSheet` by default, which can cause problems.

Comment: @braX Because `PSheet`, `DSheet` and `ActiveSheet` are all in the same workbook, an unqualified `Rows.Count` and `Columns.Count` won't cause an issue.  (But it is definitely a good idea to qualify them anyway!)

Comment: @braX am I not doing that with `DSheet.Cells` ?

Comment: Is there an on error resume next not terminated merrily hiding things?

Comment: You should also change `LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` to be `LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @YoeE3K that line didn't change things

Comment: @QHarr not sure what you mean?

Comment: Place an `On Error GoTo 0` after your `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`, so that errors aren't masked after that - it will then crash when the errors occur.

Comment: You have basically said every time you hit an error carry on. There is no On Error GoTo 0 to go with the On Error Resume Next. These two lines should wrap the lines where you expect a specific error that you want to handle in this way rather than a catch-all.

Comment: Double check the values for lastrow and lastcolumn to make sure they are what you expect by stepping thru your code.

Comment: So I find the error is at the stage of defining the PivotCache `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")` and I have changed the allocation of the last row and columns with `Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "B").Resize(LastRow, LastCol - 1)` and `LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to be LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` respectively. I still get error at the Pivot Cache stage and not sure how to check values

Comment: Doh!! Of course - you are setting your `PCache` object (which is a `PivotCache`) to the result of your `CreatePivotTable` method.  Change that line to be just `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)` (i.e. just create the cache) and see how you go.

Comment: And later on, you need to change `ActiveSheet.PivotTables` to `PSheet.PivotTables`

Comment: @YowE3K so instead of `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
'(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
'CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
'TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")` I need only `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)` followed by `Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")` ?

Comment: See the answer I posted - it has all the corrections in it (with comments showing what I changed)

Comment: And the most important lesson to have learnt is ... don't leave `On Error` active for any longer than you need to - it hides too many issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only semi-tested (due to only having dummy data) but I believe the following will fix all your errors:

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
'LastRow was not declared
Dim LastRow As Long
'LastRow1 is not used
'Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Switch off error "masking" once you don't need it
On Error GoTo 0
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")



'Define Data Range
'a) Base last row on column B if you don't have data in column A
'b) Use "DSheet.Rows.Count" and "DSheet.Columns.Count" - although not strictly
'   necessary in this situation, it is a good practice to get into
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(DSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Dsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Don't include column A in your data range
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "B").Resize(LastRow, LastCol - 1)


'Define Pivot Cache (not pivot table)
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
'Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
'(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
'CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
'TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")



'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")


'Use PSheet instead of ActiveSheet in all the following statements
'In fact, because the PTable object exists, we can just use it

'Insert Row Fields
'With AciveSheet.PivotTables("MilestonePivotTable").PivotFields("Resource Name")
'With PSheet.PivotTables("MilestonePivotTable").PivotFields("Resource Name")
With PTable.PivotFields("Resource Name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With PTable.PivotFields("Deliverable")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With PTable.PivotFields("Milestone Date")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: do you not get an "Application-defined or Object-defined error" where it is trying to insert the blank pivot `Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="MilestonePivotTable")` as that's what I get

Comment: @SDROB No, I don't get that error.  But that could be a data issue.  (E.g. if I leave a blank column within the data range I get an error about the field name being invalid, so something similar may give the error you are seeing.)  If you add a screenshot to your question showing the first couple of rows of your data, I might be able to spot something.

Comment: added image of data example above

Comment: I dummied my data up as well as I could to look like yours and it still ran OK.  Not sure what is going on.  Your headings are only on row 1?  That isn't multiple rows merged together?

Comment: No, merged rows don't cause an issue - just generates blank values in the pivot table. :(

Comment: yes I am getting it to work with dummy data too.... seems some of the cells have the drop down box next to value when you click on it.. Could this be preventing?

Comment: I just added a dummy data validation list to one cell and it didn't cause an issue.  I also tried adding some `#N/A` errors and no issues.  And I added comments (I was really struggling to think of problems!) and it didn't cause issues.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you copy half of your real data back into where you currently have dummy data.  If that works, add in half of the remainder.  If it doesn't work, delete half of what you copied.  Etc.  That might home in on what data is causing the problem.

Comment: how would I go about just using Columns A to L for the pivot? As there are further rows which I did not include in example and may be causing an issue? Also a copy and past to values might help here? Perhaps to new sheet and then take all from there?

Comment: If you just want columns B to L, use `Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, "B").Resize(LastRow, 11)`.  But does column L contain anything - it looked like it was blank.  If it is, use a `10` instead of `11`.

Comment: that fixed it!! There must be some discrepancies in some other columns which aren't needed!! Thanks for your help!